# Flutter- Is recommended to dispose() textControllers?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

The thing is have a lot of these TextEditingControllers in many screens, Login, Forms, etc.
Do I have to implement a dispose method to each of these controllers do to memory leak or it doesn't matter?

Thank you!!

I tried in some screens but I don't know if is recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should always dispose your controllers after you're done working with them, the `TextEditingController` can have a listener after you initialize it, so if you don't dispose it, it will still be running even if you navigate to other screens in your app, and this is valid for all other controllers like `AnimationController`, `StreamController`...

the change in the performance actually can't be visually clear for just some, but as your app goes bigger, it will have some performance issues.

Comment: Thanks!! yes is getting bigger and I am afraid of some performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

In the official Flutter documentation for the [TextEditingController class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html), we find the following:

> Remember to dispose of the TextEditingController when it is no longer needed. This will ensure we discard any resources used by the object.

To learn more always refer to the official Flutter documentation first.

Comment: Thank you @xaer, didn't see that doc. Thanks again!